# Suppress default message of assert_eq! when custom message provided?

Tags: testing, rust, assertion

To my surprise, when I supply a custom message, it seems that `assert_eq!`'s default message is also printed out regardless.

Here I'm comparing some very long `str`s. So it is preferable not to clutter up the console  but instead take a limited slice of each.

```
let left = tds.get_bulk_post_str();
let error_msg = format!("Bulk text is not what is expected: get_bulk_post_str() starts\n{}...\n\nExpected text starts\n{}...\n", 
    &left[0..20], &expected_bulk_text[0..20]);
// assert_eq! not used because assert_eq! apparently does not suppress its default message even when you supply a custom message!
// ... and in this case the default message is far too long.
// assert_eq!(left, expected_bulk_text, "{}", error_msg);

// instead, I think I'm forced to do something like this:
if left != expected_bulk_text {
    panic!("{}", error_msg)
}
```

... is there any way of suppressing the default message?

If not, this seems a strange design choice, unlike any other language I know. Is it deliberate?

PS I'm aware the first 20 chars of each string might be identical. Obviously if I really wanted to go to town on this I'd have to examine both strings to find out the first case of difference, and just print corresponding slices from the middle.

Comment: People might just not find your question very useful (refer to the hover text on the downvote button) You have code that let's you do what you want, it's pretty concise given that it's an extraordinary requirement, what more do you want?

Comment: OK, thanks for explaining that thinking. Yes, of course I can work that way, and it's fairly unusual. But Rust is the first language I've encountered where the default message is NOT suppressed in this context. If you supply a custom message I'd have thought this would tend to imply you don't particularly need or want the default message. For this reason I think this is a harsh judgement to deem this expectation of mine "not useful" (and particularly harsh not to explain that, unlike yourself).

Comment: This behavior seems very logical to me. Usually people do not include the values in the message, they supply _additional_ context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`assert!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.assert.html) instead:

```rust
assert!(
    left == expected_bulk_text,
    "Bulk text is not what is expected: get_bulk_post_str() starts\n\
    {}...\n\n\
    Expected text starts\n\
    {}...\n", 
    &left[0..20],
    &expected_bulk_text[0..20],
);
```